# remove (sub)item from menu-bar

Tags: menu-bar

Any way to remove an item from *menu bar* quickly/easily?

For example, I want to remove `About GNU`:

[image]

It's *a little annoying to dive into the value of keymap*.  
Moreover, *you need to know the keymap name* first (here it is `menu-bar-help-menu`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `C-h k`, click `Help`, then click `About GNU`.
   You will see the `*Help*` buffer:

   > **`<menu-bar> <help-menu> <about-gnu-project>`** runs the command `describe-gnu-project` (found in `global-map`) ... ...
2. Use an appropriate keymap setting function to remove this item.
   For example,

   ```lisp
   (keymap-global-unset "<menu-bar> <help-menu> <about-gnu-project>")
   ```